# To whom we contact to do Samashrayanam?

Tags: vaishnavism

We are Yadhavas in Chennai and like to do Samashrayanam but we don't know to whom can we go , Thenkalai OR  Vadakalai, To Sri Vaishnava Acharya or Swayamacharya people. We need guru to teach sahasranamam and other slokas and also like to visit often to get advices and informations.Please advice us.As we are new to do these procedure we need answers.
Thanks
N.DEVI

Comment: Ask @KeshavSrinivasan (He's the best guy to ask about this).

Comment: You can see the linked post for a list of Mathams.  And if you'd like to discuss further about this, my email address is on my profile page: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan?tab=profile